# I dont understand the why this UNDEFINED happen in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, dom, undefined

Why this code return me undefined in the DOM when i don't put the [0]

```js
var d = document.getElementsByName('msg')[0]
document.write(`<br> ${d.innerText}`)
```

```html
<div id="msg" name="msg">click here</div>
```

just trying to understand JS in depth

```js
var d = document.getElementsByName('msg')
document.write(`<br> ${d.innerText}`)
```

```html
<div id="msg" name="msg">click here</div>
```

Comment: Do you know what the `[0]` means?  If not then the language concept you want to research is called "arrays".  Introductory tutorials on the JavaScript language should cover that.

Answer (score 0):

Because get elements will return a collection of elements not a single element
try get element by id